# How to Convert an array object to ActiveRecord relational object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid_for_rails gem to design a table from the database. In my table few column data are coming from virtual attributes. And my jqgrid rails in loadonce => false(ie. it loads the data with the pagination unlike single time).

In my search function i have to provide the searchField what to search, but it directly hitting the database columns. So i wanted to apply the search function into an array. But not possible because it is by default searching in ActiveRecord model. So i want to convert my array object to database ActiveRecord Model.

How is it possible?

Here is my code  - Helper file

```
def order_tracker_jqgrid
options = {:on_document_ready => true, :html_tags => false}
grid = [{
  :url => '/order_tracker',
  :datatype => 'json',
  :loadonce => false,
  :mtype => 'GET',
  :height => 350,
  :altRows => true,
  :rownumbers => true,
  :colNames => ['#' , 'Order #', 'Tracking #', 'Items', 'Delivery Date', 'Current Status', 'Pickup Location', 'Created By', 'Retailer'],
  :colModel  => [
    { :name => 'id', :index => 'id', :align => 'center', :search => false, :width => 100, :hidden => true},
    { :name => 'order_number', :index => 'order_number', :classes => 'order-number',  :width => 100, :searchoptions => { :sopt => ['eq', 'cn']}},
    { :name => 'tracking_number', :index => 'tracking_number', :width => 110, :classes => 'tracking-number', :searchoptions => { :sopt => ['eq', 'cn']}},
    { :name => 'item_count', :index => 'item_count', :align => 'center' , :width => 80, :search => false},
    { :name => 'delivery_date_with_slot', :index => 'delivery_date_with_slot', :width => 200, :search => false},
    { :name => 'order_state', :index => 'order_state', :search => false},
    { :name => 'pickup_location_data', :index => 'pickup_location_data',  :jsonmap => 'pickup_location_data', :search => false},
    { :name => 'creator_name', :index => 'creator_name', :search => false},
    { :name => 'company_name', :index => 'company_name', :search => false}


  ],      
  :pager => '#grid-pager',
  :rowNum => 10,
  :rowList => [10, 20, 30],
  :sortname => 'id',
  :sortorder => 'asc',
  :viewrecords => true,      
  :autowidth => true,
  :loadComplete => "function(){var table = this;setTimeout(function(){updatePagerIcons(table);}, 0);}".to_json_var,
  :gridComplete => "function(){
                                var ids = jQuery('#grid-table').jqGrid('getRowData');                                    
                                for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ )
                                {
                                  var id = ids[i].id;  
                                  var o_number = ids[i].order_number;
                                  var t_number = ids[i].tracking_number;  
                                  var order_link = '<a href=\"/orders/'+id+'/show_incomming_order\" class=\"details fancybox fancybox.ajax\">'+o_number+'</a>';
                                  var tracker_link = '<a href=\"/order/'+t_number+'\" class=\"fancybox fancybox.ajax\">'+t_number+'</a>';
                                  $('#grid-table tr#'+id).find('.order-number').html(order_link);
                                  $('#grid-table tr#'+id).find('.tracking-number').html(tracker_link);
                                }
                           }".to_json_var
}]
pager = [:navGrid, "#grid-pager", {:del => false, :add => false, :edit => false, :searchicon => 'icon-search orange', :refreshicon => 'icon-refresh blue'}, {:closeAfterEdit => true, :closeOnEscape => true}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
jqgrid_api 'grid-table', grid, pager, options
```

end

On my controller

```
#If current user is fulflmnt admin

  @orders = OrderBucket.orders_from_cate2_3.where(search_params).order("created_at desc") #("created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, Time.zone.now.end_of_month).order("created_at desc")

@columns = ['id' , 'order_number' , 'tracking_number', 'item_count', 'delivery_date_with_slot', 'order_state', 'pickup_location_data', 'creator_name', 'company_name']    
if params[:_search] == "true"
    @orders =   @orders.search(params[:_search],params[:searchField],params[:searchString], params[:page],params[:rows],params[:searchOper],params[:sord])
else     
    sort_params = params[:sidx]  
    if sort_params == "order_number"            
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.order_number}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.order_number}.reverse.flatten
    elsif sort_params == "tracking_number"                
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.tracking_number}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.tracking_number}.reverse.flatten
    elsif sort_params == "pickup_location_data"            
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.pickup_location_data}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.pickup_location_data}.reverse.flatten
    elsif sort_params == "order_state"  
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.order_state}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.order_state}.reverse.flatten
    elsif sort_params == "creator_name"      
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.creator_name}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.creator_name}.reverse.flatten
    elsif sort_params == "company_name"          
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.company_name}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.company_name}.reverse.flatten
    elsif sort_params == "delivery_date_with_slot"              
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.delivery_date_with_slot}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.delivery_date_with_slot}.reverse.flatten
    elsif sort_params == "item_count"              
        @orders = params[:sord] == "asc" ? @orders.sort_by{|p| p.item_count}.flatten : @orders.sort_by{|p| p.item_count}.reverse.flatten
    end

    @orders = @orders.paginate(
        :page     => params[:page],
        :per_page => params[:rows],
        :order    => order_by_from_params(params))

end
if request.xhr?
  render :json => json_for_jqgrid(@orders, @columns)
end
```

and on my model

## search method to find data for jqGrid order table

def self.search(_search,searchField, searchString,page,rows,searchOper,sord)

```
if searchOper == 'cn' && _search # contains
  wildcard_search = "%#{searchString}%" 
  where("#{searchField} LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search).page(page).per_page(rows)
elsif searchOper == 'nc' && _search # does not contain
  wildcard_search = "%#{searchString}%" 
  where.not("#{searchField} LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search).page(page).per_page(rows)
elsif searchOper == 'bw' && _search # begin with
  wildcard_search = "#{searchString}%"
  where("#{searchField} LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search).page(page).per_page(rows)    
elsif searchOper == 'bn' && _search # does not begin with
  wildcard_search = "#{searchString}%"
  where.not("#{searchField} LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search).page(page).per_page(rows)    
elsif searchOper == 'en' && _search # does not end with
  wildcard_search = "%#{searchString}"
  where.not("#{searchField} LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search).page(page).per_page(rows) 
elsif searchOper == 'ew' && _search # ends with
  wildcard_search = "%#{searchString}"
  where("#{searchField} LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search).page(page).per_page(rows)
elsif searchOper == 'eq' && _search # equal
 where("#{searchField} = :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows)  
elsif searchOper == 'ne' && _search # not equal
  where.not("#{searchField} = :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows)
elsif searchOper == 'in' && _search # is in 
  # where("#{searchField} = :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows)      
elsif searchOper == 'ni' && _search # is in 
  # where("#{searchField} = :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows)  
elsif searchOper == 'lt' && _search # less 
  where("#{searchField} < :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows)  
elsif searchOper == 'le' && _search # less or equal
  where("#{searchField} <= :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows)
elsif searchOper == 'gt' && _search # greater
  where("#{searchField} > :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows) 
elsif searchOper == 'ge' && _search # greater or equal 
  where("#{searchField} >= :search", search: searchString).page(page).per_page(rows)
else
  wildcard_search = "%#{searchString}%" # contains
  where("name LIKE :search", search: wildcard_search).page(page).per_page(rows)    
end
```

end

Comment: showing some of your existing code will help!

Comment: Hey. i have updated the code. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

I think I got something that can work. I never used it though so I can't guarantee about its stability (and if you use it I would like your feedback please)

So let's work this example with `User` model. You got an array with few `user` records

```
array = [User.find(5), User.find(50), User.find(500)]
```

You can create an empty relation object

```
# Rails 4: `none` is going to be the easiest and most efficient
relation = User.none

# Rails 3: we have to cheat
relation = User.where('1 = 0')
```

And add them one by one

```
relation << array[0]
relation << array[2]
```

Or all at once

```
relation += array
```

Comment: Hey. I have updated it with my code. You might more clear idea now. And i have tried your code. But on the last step "relation += array" it automatically get converted into and Array object

Comment: So you mean `(relation += array).class.name` output `Array`? Weird. But for the little I tried it works as expected in Rails 4. Any change to upgrade your project? (you will need a full test coverage before that)

Answer (score 0):

To convert an array object to ActiveRecord relational object, just perform the following:

`MyModel.where(id: my_arr.map(&:id))`

- (a) `MyModel` is the class which the objects in array are
- (b) `arr` is the array object